# What is the difference between (0:2):4 and 0:(2:4)?

Tags: matlab

What is the difference between `(0:2):4` and `0:(2:4)`?
Both neglects the 2nd part of the bracket thus printing values similar to writing `(0:4)` and `(0:2)` respectively.

I could generalize from this that the bracket's first element is only working in this vector. But I would like to know the actual reason why is it happening.

Answer (score 2):

the `colon` operator has lower priority than `()`, so, matlab first evaluates the vector inside the parenthesis, then, if one of the operands is a vector, `colon` only takes the first value. here are the evaluation steps:

```
(0:2):4 -> (0:2)=[0 1 2] -> 0:4 -> [0,1,2,3,4]
0:(2:4) -> (2:4)=[2 3 4] -> 0:2 -> [0,1,2]
```

Comment: it becomes more apparent if you count to a larger number in the columns: `(0:10):4 == [0 1 2 3 4]`